# Microsoft Web Farm Framework 502 error

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-farm

My apologies if this is a really stupid question, but I have installed and set up the new Microsoft Web Farm Framework in a UAT environment with a controller machine, a primary, and a secondary server. I have installed one of our in-house applications on to the primary server and it has been successfully provisioned across to the secondary.

I have tried accessing the server via the url http:\mis-uat-002\testfarm\reviewer where mis-uat-002 is the name of the farm controller, testfarm is the name of the farm, and reviewer is the name of the application. When using this url I get a "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server." error.

If I access the application directly via http:\mis-uat-003\reviewer (mis-uat-003 is the primary farm server, reviewer is the application) then it works no problem.

Is there some additional set up that needs to be done in order for the farm controller to do its job?

It should be noted that this is a UAT environment so is not on a domain of any sort. However, if this was successful and the WFF came out with V1.0 fairly soon, we would be looking to run this on a Windows 2008 domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because your farm members are not set to as being available for load balancing.